# Trying to figure out how to fetch data from the database and output to an excel file. Not sure what to try next

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Ok so here is my problem. I am trying to fetch data from a database and output all the data to an excel spread sheet or even a text document.
Whichever is easier.

Eventually i want it to be in excel though.

I am pretty new to this and have been looking for multiple answers for going on three weeks.

Any help is appreciated.

```
//Export to excel
         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Download()
        {


            List<string> persons = new List<string> { };
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=WebApplication1;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT RMAFormModels AS cusName FROM RMAFormModels ", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // Check is the reader has any rows at all before starting to read.
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        // Read advances to the next row.
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            RMAFormModels p = new RMAFormModels();

                            // To avoid unexpected bugs access columns by name.
                            p.cusName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("cusName"));
                            //p.FirstName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
                            // int middleNameIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("MiddleName");
                            // If a column is nullable always check for DBNull...
                            //if (!reader.IsDBNull(middleNameIndex))
                            // {
                            //     p.MiddleName = reader.GetString(middleNameIndex);
                            //  }
                            // p.LastName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName"));
                            // persons.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

                // Use persons here...

                // var name = collection.cusName;
                //var date = collection.DatePurchased;
                //var dateIssued = collection.DateIssued;

                /* List<Lookup> collection = new List<Lookup>();
                 var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

                 grid.DataSource = collection;
                 grid.DataBind();

                 Response.ClearContent();
                 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelTest.xlsx");
                 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                 //Response.ContentType = "application / vnd.openxmlformats - officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

                 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                 HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                 grid.RenderControl(htw);
                 Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                 Response.End();
                 */
                //customer = new cusName();
                // cusName = "Tod";



                var string_with_your_data = persons ;

            //List<>.ToCharArray(string_with_your_data);

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string_with_your_data);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            return File(stream, "text/plain", "your_file_name.txt"); // this goes to a file.txt


            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want this to be a web page that exports to excel. I recommend using an ApiController method that outputs an HttpResultMessage. Make the content be a CSV text representation  of the table. Make the Content-Type be text/csv and add a file name to the http header section. In Windows anyone who has CSV files associated with Excel will have the option to open the downloaded file and it will automatically open into excel.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with ClosedXML nuget Package. I hope that it will be useful to you too.

1. add ClosedXML nuget Package to your project.
2. You will need to importClosedXML.Excel namespace

3.Export action

```
    [HttpPost]
        public FileResult Export()
        {       
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Grid");
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("CustomerId"),
                                            new DataColumn("ContactName"),
                                            new DataColumn("City"),
                                            new DataColumn("Country") });

        var customers = GetCustomers(); //get customer from database;

        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(customer.CustomerID, customer.ContactName, customer.City, customer.Country);
        }

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(stream);
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Grid.xlsx");
            }
        }
    }
```

4.on the View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Export"/>
    }
```